# XO Relation with properties throws exception

Tags: jqassistant

For a [jQAssistant](http://www.jqassistant.org/) plugin, I created a relationship descriptor as described in http://buschmais.github.io/extended-objects/doc/0.8.0/neo4j/#_unidirectional_relations

It looks like this:

```java
@Relation
public interface PlantUmlSequenceDiagramMessageDescriptor 
    extends Descriptor {

    @Relation.Outgoing
    PlantUmlParticipantDescriptor getSourceParticipant();

    @Relation.Incoming
    PlantUmlParticipantDescriptor getTargetParticipant();

    void setMessage(String messageText);
    String getMessage();

    void setMessageNumber(String messageNumber);
    String getMessageNumber();
}
```

But when using it:

```java
final PlantUmlSequenceDiagramMessageDescriptor messageDescriptor = 
    store.create(p1, PlantUmlSequenceDiagramMessageDescriptor.class, p2);
```

I get an exception:

```
2017-12-21 19:37:16.591 [main] ERROR ScannerImpl - Unexpected problem encountered while scanning: item='plantuml\src\test\plantuml\sequence.puml', path='/sequence.puml', scope='NONE', pipeline='[com.buschmais.jqassistant.plugin.common.impl.scanner.FileResourceSc
annerPlugin@65d93024, de.kontext_e.jqassistant.plugin.plantuml.scanner.PlantUmlFileScannerPlugin@72dcb917]'. Please report this error including the full stacktrace (continueOnError=true).
com.buschmais.xo.api.XOException: Cannot resolve property in type 'de.kontext_e.jqassistant.plugin.plantuml.store.descriptor.PlantUmlParticipantDescriptor' for relation type 'de.kontext_e.jqassistant.plugin.plantuml.store.descriptor.PlantUmlSequenceDiagramMessag
eDescriptor'.
    at com.buschmais.xo.impl.metadata.RelationTypeMetadataResolver.getRelationPropertyMethodMetadata(RelationTypeMetadataResolver.java:131)
    at com.buschmais.xo.impl.metadata.MetadataProviderImpl.getPropertyMetadata(MetadataProviderImpl.java:146)
    at com.buschmais.xo.impl.XOManagerImpl.createByExample(XOManagerImpl.java:288)
    at com.buschmais.xo.impl.XOManagerImpl.create(XOManagerImpl.java:272)
    at com.buschmais.jqassistant.core.store.impl.AbstractGraphStore.create(AbstractGraphStore.java:83)
    at de.kontext_e.jqassistant.plugin.plantuml.scanner.PumlLineParser.addEvent(PumlLineParser.java:286)
```

What is the correct way to create a Relation with properties? I tried alread to add also setters for Outgoing and Incoming relations, does not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you create the relation is correct. However, the exception message indicates that you have not mapped the relation in the `PlantUmlParticipantDescriptor`. In your case, the `PlantUmlParticipantDescriptor` interface should look something like this:

```
@Label
public interface PlantUmlParticipantDescriptor {
    @Relation.Outgoing
    Set<PlantUmlSequenceDiagramMessageDescriptor> getSource();

    @Relation.Incoming
    Set<PlantUmlSequenceDiagramMessageDescriptor> getTarget();
}

@Relation
public interface PlantUmlSequenceDiagramMessageDescriptor {

    @Relation.Outgoing
    PlantUmlParticipantDescriptor getSourceParticipant();

    @Relation.Incoming
    PlantUmlParticipantDescriptor getTargetParticipant();

    void setMessage(String messageText);
    String getMessage();

    void setMessageNumber(String messageNumber);
    String getMessageNumber();
}
```

Then you can set the properties as expected:

```
PlantUmlParticipantDescriptor  t1 = this.xoManager.create(PlantUmlParticipantDescriptor.class);
PlantUmlParticipantDescriptor  t2 = this.xoManager.create(PlantUmlParticipantDescriptor .class);
PlantUmlSequenceDiagramMessageDescriptor d = this.xoManager.create(t1, PlantUmlSequenceDiagramMessageDescriptor.class, t2);
d.setMessage("Test Message");
```